# Casting STRING to DATE in Impala. (Possible bugs)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala, hue, bigdata

This seems to be an interesting bug/problem I am facing. I am using Impala and HUE which comes under CDH 5.8 (Cloudera Distribution for Hadoop).

On executing the below code

```
select '1709.02.02' as DateString, CAST((from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1709.02.02','yyyy.MM.dd'))) as TIMESTAMP) as DateTimestamp
```

I get output as follows (which is expected)

```
datestring  datetimestamp
1709.02.02  1709-02-02 00:00:00
```

But on executing the code below

```
select '1009.02.02' as DateString, CAST((from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1009.02.02','yyyy.MM.dd'))) as TIMESTAMP) as DateTimestamp
```

The output displayed is as follows (which is not expected):

```
datestring  datetimestamp
1009.02.02  NULL
```

Can someone kindly shed a light as to why this is happening and/or suggest a possible way-around?

PS: It seems to work fine if the above query is run in Hive. But in Impala we are getting NULL values.

Comment: I think Impala has a limit on year. 1400 to 10000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Impala only supports TIMESTAMPs within the years 1400 to 9999, so any TIMESTAMP values outside of those ranges will be NULL.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_timestamp.html#timestamp

Comment: Thank you for answering @Matt. Its pretty cool that you are working in Apache Impala. :) Coming back to this matter, can you please tell me if there is a way-around? Also, are there any plans for extending the date range in future?

Comment: Hi @ArshSheth - I'd recommend storing your dates as strings or BIGINT (e.g. seconds since some epoch). There are downsides to both, unfortunately. There is no immediate work happening to support dates outside of this range. Unfortunately the current TIMESTAMP type is limited by the underlying boost library Impala uses.

Comment: You can also consider writing separate fields, e.g. INT year, TINYINT month, TINYINT day, ...